# How to make different flashcards appear when you hover over different parts of an image

Tags: html

I'm making a website about dragons, and I'd like to have a map of the world that will give you information about some famous dragons when you hover over the country they're from. I've placed circles on different points of a map, and I want different cards to appear when I hover over each of them, but the only function I've found for interactive images  is Image Map, and that just brings you to a new page.

```
      src="https://cdn.glitch.com/68958969-8a64-449b-99cf-41f11e779bac%2Fkayas%20other%20map%20thing.jpg?v=1610909318736"
      usemap="#workmap"
    />

    <map name="workmap">
      <area
        shape="circle" coords="1090,436,28" alt="Computer" href="computer.htm"
      />
    </map>
```

If anyone knows how do this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Using coordinates isn't useful most of the time, try something like this:

CSS:

```
.map {
    position: absolute;
}

.map img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}

.map a {
    position: absolute;
    top: 53%;
    left: 21%;
    width: 4%;
    height: 4%;
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:center;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.map a + a {
    top: 30%;
    left: 44%;
    width: 4%;
    height: 4%;
    transform-origin: bottom right
}

.map a + a + a{
    top: 20%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 4%;
    height: 4%;
    transform-origin: bottom right
}


.map a + a + a + a{
    top: 40%;
    left: 51%;
    width: 4%;
    height: 4%;
    transform-origin: bottom right
}

.map a + a + a + a + a{
    top: 43%;
    left: 55%;
    width: 4%;
    height: 4%;
    transform-origin: bottom right
}

.map a + a + a + a + a + a{
    top: 40%;
    left: 69%;
    width: 4%;
    height: 4%;
    transform-origin: bottom right
}

.tooltip {
  text-decoration:none;
  position:relative;
}
 
.tooltip span {
  display:none;
  -moz-border-radius:6px;
  -webkit-border-radius:6px;
  border-radius:6px;
  color:black;
  background:white; 
}
 

 
.tooltip:hover span {
  display:inline-block;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100px;
  min-height: 100px;
  border:1px solid black;
  padding:8px;
}

.image {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="map">
  <img src="https://cdn.glitch.com/68958969-8a64-449b-99cf-41f11e779bac%2Fkayas%20other%20map%20thing.jpg?v=1610909318736" />
  <a class="tooltip" href="">
   <!-- you can put text here to go in the circles if you wish -->
   <span><img class="image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" width="600px" height="300px">
   <h3>Red dragon <br></h3>
    This dragon is from Central america
   </span>
  </a>

  <a class="tooltip" href="">
   <span><img class="image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" width="200px" height="200px">
   <h3>Red dragon</h3>
    This dragon is from the United Kingdom
   </span>
  </a>

  <a class="tooltip" href="">
   <span><img class="image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" width="600px" height="300px">
   <h3>Red dragon</h3>
    This dragon is from Scandinavia
   </span>
  </a>

  <a class="tooltip" href="">
   <span><img class="image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" width="600px" height="300px">
   <h3>Red dragon</h3>
    This dragon is from Greece
   </span>
  </a>

  <a class="tooltip" href="">
   <span><img class="image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" width="600px" height="300px">
   <h3>Red dragon</h3>
    This dragon is from Syria
   </span>
  </a>

  <a class="tooltip" href="">
   <span><img class="image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" width="600px" height="300px">
   <h3>Red dragon</h3>
    This dragon is from China
   </span>
  </a>
</div>
```

I used "+ a" for the CSS, you can change these to class names too.

Comment: wait, how do I actually put content in the links. Sorry, I'm kinda new to this and I don't fully understand how to make the links in the map show stuff.

Comment: How exactly do you want the dragon information to be displayed? You can have a [modal](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp) so when they click the area a box shows up, a text over [hover](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_tooltip.asp), or text when they click the circles.

Comment: @AmythistArira check my edited question, that should work for you now. I'd recommend adding width and height to the end of each image, because of course they will be different sizes. Or you can make individual classes :)

Comment: thanks, this is amazing, but quick question, why is the text so big?

Comment: @AmythistArira I believe it is just because there is no assigned font size so it's automatically that size. You can edit the size by going to the "tooltip" class and typing "font-size: "